# unity, android and networking

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Im coding a VR game for google cardboard, the game runs in the phone (Android) then I have a machine (windows) that tracks the hands and send information to the game so the virtual hands move with the real ones.

The hand tracking works nice, the game works nice BUT .. the connectivity is broken.

I developed the client/server based in tcp .net sockets and now I discover that sockets are closed for the free version of anrdoid sdk.

What are my options? stuff like photon, appwarp ? are they free? this is a hobbyist project so no budget at all. would bluetooth work? I can buy a BT dongle for the PC, does Unity have BT interfaces ? 
Any other free solution ??

Comment: *I discover that sockets are closed for the free version of android sdk* ?! Can you clarify what you mean by this? The Android SDK does not impose limits or restrictions on apps.

Comment: for instance here they talk about the topic: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/141135/net-socket-support-for-iosandroid.html    Could it be that Unity 5 solves the issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Unity 5 this is not the case anymore. .Net Sockets work out of the box.